# What is a process in Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently browsing the node documentation and I'm trying to understand what really is a process in Node. (that's my main question)

[In the part about processes](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html), we can see all kinds of functions relative to the global process variable:

```
process.stdout;    // A writable stream to stdout.
process.stderr;    // A writable stream to stderr.
process.stdin;     // A readable stream for stdin.
process.argv;      // An array containing the command line arguments.
process.execPath;  // This is the absolute pathname of the executable that started the process.
```

It says for instance that process.execPath returns the absolute pathname of the executable that started the process.

My question is what could be this executable? Can an executable run many processes? What really is a process in Node? Can I run myself a process and in what situation should I do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This executable is always Node. `process` refers to the current node process running your script. There is only one process, although you can fork it, but then it creates a new process so you still only have one process.

For example, if you run:

```
node myscript.js
```

The execPath may be `/usr/bin/node` (mine is `/opt/nodejs/bin/node`). `process` is very useful for managing the node process running your code.

Comment: Thank you I see it now. By the way, why some people have downvoted this question, is it a stupid question? (I'm trying to understand for next time)

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec Mostly because the question was answered right in the documentation and people on SO can be trigger happy with downvotes